# How to make EF to query context first and if not found, to query DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a program that add a lot of data to database using EF. One of the data is a record that should be unique in database, so, I have this instruction:

```
DataWare.Funcionario funcionario = db.Funcionario.Where(f => f.FunRut.Equals(rut)).FirstOrDefault();
```

If "funcionario" is not found,a new object is created and added to context this way:

```
db.Funcionario.Add(funcionario);
```

This is inside a foreach cicle. When in some iteration, we encounter the same "funcionario", the Where method above returns null, even when it was already added to context.

After the foreach, I have saving changes to context.

I have been searching around, and I have found that method always query the database and I could use Local property to query objects already in context, however, that way I have 2 problems. First, it always query only the Local instances, so I will need to make 2 calls explicitly, in order to query the database in case it is not found in context. The second problem, and the worst, is that when I call SaveChanges to context, it saves many duplicates of the same records. I don't know why. Maybe this is caused to the Local and Database data not synchronized.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Jaime

EDIT:

This is the actual scenario: I have a List<> that actually stores a lot of time attendance events for the staff of a company. That event comes from a time attendance device.

The foreach I was talking about is the foreach through that List. That event and the staff should be created in my database in case it does not already exist.

If a staff does not exist, system does a remote call to another system to retrieve staff information and then saved that information into our own system. If staff was already added, it should use that instance instead of creating a new one. By the way, the same staff can generate several events during the day. So I add that event to my own system associating the found staff or the new created one.

This is the full code of the foreach for your reference:

```
        using (DataWare.SistemasBCIEntities db = new DataWare.SistemasBCIEntities())
        {
            bool exito = false;

            foreach (var log in logs.OrderBy(l => l.EnrollNumber))
            {
                string rut = log.EnrollNumber.ToString();
                DataWare.Funcionario funcionario = db.Funcionario.Where(f => f.FunRut.Equals(rut)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (funcionario == null)
                    funcionario = GetPersonFromZKTime(rut, db);

                if (funcionario != null)
                {
                    // Si ya hay un evento para esa hora y ese funcionario, debe continuar con el siguiente
                    DataWare.Evento evento = db.Evento.Where(e => e.EveFechaHora.Equals(log.Date) && e.Funcionario.FunRut.Equals(rut)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (evento == null)
                    {
                        exito = true;

                        string tipoEvento = String.Empty;
                        if (log.InOutMode == DataWare.Terminal.InOutModeEnum.Check_In || log.InOutMode == DataWare.Terminal.InOutModeEnum.OT_In || log.InOutMode == DataWare.Terminal.InOutModeEnum.Break_In)
                            tipoEvento = "IN";
                        else
                            tipoEvento = "OUT";
                        evento = new DataWare.Evento()
                        {
                            Funcionario = funcionario,
                            EveFechaHora = log.Date,
                            EveTipo = tipoEvento,
                            EveFechaCreacion = DateTime.Now
                        };

                        db.Evento.Add(evento);
                    }
                }
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

            return exito;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the fields that are used to find the records to be primary keys, then I have used Find method of EF and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can just check to see if the id has been set otherwise set the entity state like this:

```
foreach(var rut in source.Distinct()) 
{       
    db.Entry(rut).State = rut.Id == 0 ? 
                               EntityState.Added : 
                               EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Comment: record is always added, not modified, I just needed to get the already added record.